# PayPal gateway has rejected request. A successful transaction has already been completed for this token

Tags: error, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-standard

I'm getting the following error after paypal payment

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. A successful transaction has
>   already been completed for this token (#10415: Transaction refused
>   because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for
>   details).

Checkout: onepage

The error occurs only if the cart contains **virtual product** (services and downloadable). If I add a "*physical*" product all works fine.
When I get the error, Paypal complete the payment but Magento did not create the order.

Comment: Looking for the answer, same problem. :( Not very often but still :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved disabling HHVM cache on my server

Comment: what do you mean HHVM cacge??

Comment: @SunilPatel Did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue with the exact error on Magento 2.4.5.